# Set default date as DateTime.Now for DateEdit

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to set the default date for dateEdit picker, but I can access it only with controls, and the way I did below, it does not modify the original DateEdit, how could I do? Thank you very much

```
GridViewToolbarItem dateEditItem = toolbar.Items.FindByName("ASPxDateEditItem");
ASPxDateEdit dayDate = dateEditItem.FindControl("deDateFrom") as ASPxDateEdit;
dayDate.Date = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: MVC or WebForms? In MVC, when you first create your page, pass in a 'default' `viewmodel` with the values that you want as the defaults, and bind the page (including the date picker) to the viewmodel. In ASP.Net webforms, make sure you are setting those values in the `Page_Load` (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/ms178472(v=vs.85) ) . Or use javascript to do it client-side, but only do this for things that users are allowed to modify. And *ALWAYS* validate the data coming back from the form response.

Comment: yes, but I did not find a way to put as default Date.Now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see
https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.ASPxDateEdit

They're is an example there that includes setting default properties.

1. Ensure you are changing properties of the control in the `Page_Load` method in web forms. I said this in my comment, but you didn't confirm.
2. Ensure you are getting a reference to your web control. Put a breakpoint where you get a reference to your web control, and inspect it to ensure it is populated as expected.
3. Use `DateTime.Today` to set the value, not `DateTime.Now`